# Creating large number of simlinks

Tags: bash, unix, shell, symbolic-link

I have 335 pathes to same files (some with different names)

```
DarkestDungeon/colours/default_colour_grade.png
DarkestDungeon/dlc/735730_color_of_madness/dungeons/farm/colour_grade.png
DarkestDungeon/dungeons/cove/colour_grade.png
DarkestDungeon/dlc/702540_shieldbreaker/monsters/snake_big_adder/snake_big_adder_B/tint.png
DarkestDungeon/dlc/702540_shieldbreaker/monsters/snake_big_adder/snake_big_adder_C/tint.png
```

[...](https://pastebin.com/q71AXTsH)

its pollible to create 334 relative symlinks (ln -s) to first file with one command?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Too bad the question isn't about multiple [`hardlink`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/hardlink.1.html)s.